# text box exit event in multipage userform

Tags: vba, excel, exit, multipage

I have multipage user form which has sub multipage. the text box exit event is not working it is working when userform exits. So I have tried the after update event. It works fine but I am not able to set focus the textbox if the entered value is not numeric. the code is working fine. userform doesnt show the previos page text box. 
below is the screen shot and code
[image: multipage screenshot]

---

---

At page no 4 I have text box and once the details entered,I click the page2 to proceed. before that I need to check whether the entered detaisl is numeric or not. If its not numeric I have to show the page4 and focus on text box1 to re-enter the details that is not working. please help me guys.

```
Private Sub TextBox3_AfterUpdate()
  If Len(UserForm1.TextBox3.Value) <> 0 And _ 
    IsNumeric(UserForm1.TextBox3.Value) = False Then
    UserForm1.MultiPage1.Value = 0
    userform1.multipage2.value = 1
    UserForm1.TextBox3.SetFocus
    MsgBox "Only Numbers are Allowed!!"

  End If
End Sub
```

the code didnot show error but Its not focusing on the text box still showing the page2.

Comment: Are you sure you are putting this all in the correct userform? your code indicates Userform1, but the image indicates Userform2

Comment: What error are you getting? What are you attempting to do with `UserForm1.MultiPage1.Value = 0`? Shouldn't this be something like `UserForm1.MultiPage1.TextBox1.Value = 0`?

Comment: @Xabier I am not getting any error. [link]( UserForm1.MultiPage1.Value = 0) with this I am trying to show or navigate the multipage page 1 in the user form. because once I enter the value in text box if i click on another mulitpage say multipage page2, that will appear and then I want to navigate to the text box which is in multipage1 page4 if it is not a numeric

Comment: @TaylorScott its is userform1 only the screenshot is for reference to show here.

Comment: Do you also have code in a userform event that navigates to page2 after the correct value is in the textbox? Sometimes userform events fire in an unexpected order....

Comment: Also, for the exit textbox event to fire, the user needs to click on another object in the same multipage tab as the textbox. I believe if the user directly selects page2, the event that will fire is the multipage2 exit event. However, if the user selects page3, there won't be any exit event firing....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Messagebox interrupts set Focus**

Displaying a messagebox (window) interrupts your `SetFocus` code. In order to *work around* this issue just redisplay the userform after hiding via

```
Me.Hide: Me.Show
```

*Another approach would be to display the error message by a **Label** caption message.*

**Modified example using your original code:**

```
Private Sub TextBox3_AfterUpdate()
If Len(Me.TextBox3.Value) <> 0 And _
   IsNumeric(Me.TextBox3.Value) = False Then
     Me.MultiPage1.Value = 0
     MsgBox "Only Numbers are allowed!!"
     Me.MultiPage2.Value = 1
     Me.TextBox3.SetFocus

     Me.Hide: Me.Show     ' << work around by redisplaying userform
End If
End Sub
```

**Hint**

*It's better to use the `Me.` prefix than `UserForm1.` within the userform code module itself to identify controls (and allow IntelliSense).*

Comment: I have tried with out pop outing the msgbox. Still it remains the same. its not navigating to the previos multipage text box. Also I have tried the hide and show. didnt work out

Comment: @sabarigiri, This worked for me without problems (assume code resides in your userform code module) - did you set focus *after* the msgbox and multiplage statements as shown in code above?

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using keydown events to prevent non numeric input all together with something like this

```vb
''  allows checking numlock 
Private Declare Function GetKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal nVirtKey As Long) As Integer
Private Const ksCapital As Long = 20
Private Const ksNumLock As Long = 144


Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Select Case KeyCode
        Case vbKeyBack, vbKeyDelete, vbKeyLeft, vbKeyRight, vbKeyInsert, vbKeyNumlock
            ''  allow deleting, moving, changing numlock
        Case Asc(0) To Asc(9)
            ''  if input is a number, not a symbol let it remain
            If Shift Eqv Not GetKeyState(ksNumLock) Then KeyCode = 0
        Case Asc("-")
            ''  allow negatives
            If InStr(1, Me.TextBox1.Text, "-") > 0 Or Me.TextBox1.SelStart > 0 Then Let KeyCode = 0
        Case Asc(".")
            ''  allow decimals
            If InStr(1, Me.TextBox1.Text, ".") > 0 Then Let KeyCode = 0
        Case Else
            ''  allow nothing else
            Let KeyCode = 0
    End Select
End Sub
```